# Why aws lamba keep on executing after intervals even after removing cloudwatch event?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Lambda function(written in java) which was scheduled to execute every 15mins  and it will run for next 15 mins( as this is the highest value for lambda timeout). So this is how the architecture looks: CloudwatchEvent(every 15mins) -----> Lambda(Runs for 15mins)

I have removed the cloudwatch event from lambda console but still I can see it has been invoked for few hours every 15 mins. Is this a bug or some architectural concept issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did u forget to save the lambda function after removing the CWE? You can even check it in the Cloudwatch event console, the respective CWE Rule is still mapped to the lambda function or not?

Comment: Yes, I have saved it and can't see cloudwatch event/bridge in linked in lambda event anymore. I have also confirmed from cloudwatch console. And it continues only for few hours only after that this doesn't happen.

Comment: If the event gets throttled or errored out, lambda may retry

Comment: So you are saying that lambda might have thrown error so even after the event source removed lambda keeps retrying?